# Reactive Forms - Appending Values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am working with a reactive form and I am able to append some values from it in order to send an `http` request make a post. It works when I append text or a file, but I am not sure how to append a date or a boolean or an array.

```
addPost(postAdded: Post, image: File) {
    const postData = new FormData();
    postData.append("title", postAdded.title); // string
    postAdded.append("startDate", postAdded.startDate); // date
    postAdded.append("private", postAdded.private); // boolean
    postAdded.append("image", image, postAdded.title); // file
    this.http
      .post<{ postId: string }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/posts",
        postAdded
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        this.potsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      });
  }
```

The error I get is the following:

> Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
>     Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

or

> Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.ts(2345)

and finally the error for array

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
>     Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

When using a boolean

The booleans are for toggles, dates for datepickers.

How could I do it?

Comment: You declare `postData`, but you're appending to `betData`. Where is that getting declared?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the date should be added in right format. Try this:

```
var datestr = (new Date(postAdded.startDate)).toUTCString();
formdata.append("start", datestr);
```

For boolean items:

```
formdata.append(prop, JSON.stringify(postAdded.private));
```

For arrays:

```
for (let i = 0; i < postAdded.participants.length; i ++) {
    formdata.append(prop, JSON.stringify(postAdded.participants[i]));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to mark the solution as not the correct one again because, while it actually works, using stringify I store the information as a string, so in the database is shown as   "participants":["[\"MARIO\",\"MARIO\",\"MARIO\"]"]   meaning that it does not store anymore the value as an array with several elements, but only as an array with one long string